# Simplifying code for formatting phone numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What I'm trying to accomplish is to take a string, and parse it so it is just the numbers.  Then when displaying it, I'll use the number_to_phone and they'll all be the same.

So far I have this defined in my model:

```
  def parse_phone_nums
    self.main_phone = self.main_phone.gsub(/[.\-()\W]/, '') if self.main_phone
    self.alt_phone = self.alt_phone.gsub(/[.\-()\W]/, '') if self.alt_phone
    self.main_phone = "925" + self.main_phone if self.main_phone.length == 7
    self.alt_phone = "925" + self.alt_phone if self.alt_phone.length == 7
  end
```

And call it in my controller on the create and update actions.  I feel as if there is a lot of repetition here and was wondering how one might reduce the code to be as DRY as possible.

Comment: I don't believe your code runs without error.

Comment: You see what the repeated code is (and hopefully the logic error), are you sure you cannot come up with *any* way to remove that dupliation?! Perhaps a method of some sort?

Comment: @oldergod you're right, I forgot the double equals in the comparison - besides that, it works fine

Comment: @DaveNewton although I could have moved it to another method and reduced it a bit, there are pieces of logic that I would not think of and was looking to make it as dry as possible, mainly for educational benefit not any functional benefit

Comment: @cadlac No, your code does not make sense. if you test `if self.main_phone` it means `main_phone` can be `nil` and if it is `nil`, `if self.main_phone.length == 7` raises an error too.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution of many, roughly:

```
def clean_up_phone(num)
  return unless num
  num = num.gsub(/[.\-()\W]/, '')
  num.length == 7 ? "925#{num}" : num
end
```

There are a number of ways this method could be used, including automatically on setting, during a callback, and so on.

I'm not sure the regex is what you really want, people enter quite  a few things for phone numbers. You may want to process it a  bit more before validation, and add the area code after that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this, since it allows for future extension (another area code? detect area codes submitted by the user, etc) and is easily testable.

And since it's easy to forget a matcher for a character that the user might use, I'd use a different approach for extracting the number from the given String.

```
def parse_phone_nums
  self.main_phone = parse_phone_number(self.main_phone) if self.main_phone
  self.alt_phone  = parse_phone_number(self.alt_phone)  if self.alt_phone
end

private

def parse_phone_number(string)
  number = extract_number(string)
  prefix_area_code(number)
end

def extract_number(string)
  characters = string.split("")
  characters.reduce("") { |memo, char| "#{memo}#{char}" if numeric?(char) }
end

def prefix_area_code(number)
  prefix = number.length == 7 ? "925" : ""
  "#{prefix}#{number}"
end

def numeric?(string)
  Float(string) != nil rescue false
end
```

Ideally I'd extract all these `private` methods into a own class, let's say a PhoneNumberParser.

If you think `def_phone_nums` is not DRY enough, or if you have many more phone numbers, this should work:

```
def parse_phone_nums
  phones = %w[main alt]
  phones.each do |phone|
    current = self.send("#{phone}_phone")
    next unless current

    parsed = parse_phone_number(current)
    self.send("#{phone}_phone=", parsed)
  end
end
```